# about socket connection in webrtc using socket,io

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

i am study about peer to peer video chat and i follow the google Codelab for study.and i am just read theoretical part about webrtc from html 5 rocks website, so i'm not aware too much about coding part of socket connection.

link of code lab is 
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/webrtc-web/#2
please visit step 05.

and i didn't understand following part from "main.js" file.

```
socket.on('message', function(message) {
  console.log('Client received message:', message);
  if (message === 'got user media') {
    maybeStart();
  } else if (message.type === 'offer') {
    if (!isInitiator && !isStarted) {
      maybeStart();
    }
    pc.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(message));
    doAnswer();
  } else if (message.type === 'answer' && isStarted) {
    pc.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(message));
  } else if (message.type === 'candidate' && isStarted) {
    var candidate = new RTCIceCandidate({
      sdpMLineIndex: message.label,
      candidate: message.candidate
    });
    pc.addIceCandidate(candidate);
  } else if (message === 'bye' && isStarted) {
    handleRemoteHangup();
  }
});
```

so my quetion is

1)what is message.type === 'offer' and what is offer what kind of string it is? same for 'answer' and 'candidate' also .

and can you gave me flow that how exactly this code works please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WebRTC use signalling to create a connection. Signalling is basically the messages fired back and forth between peers via websockets. You can use something like sockets.io for this.

Signalling helps establish a connection and maintain it. The signalling sends session description protocol info' back and forth.

The signalling or socket messages used to establish a connection consists of an offer and an answer.

It looks like this:

- Participant 1 (P1) joins and let's people know they are there over
  sockets
- Participant 2 (P2) responds with an offer sent over sockets
- P1 receives the offer and stores P2's details as the remote description
- P1 sends back an answer containing their details P2 receives this
  answer and stores P1's details as the remote description
- Connected!

The information is called Session Description Protocol (SDP). It contains information like:

- Multimedia type (audio, video, screen share)
- Media capability
- Transport addresses
- Metadata

There is a detailed explanation on my blog if you are interested.

https://blog.videorooms.io/2018/05/mesh-architecture.html

The socket simply sends JSON back and forth between two people that are trying to connect with each other.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hmm...do you mean to recommend [socket.io](https://socket.io/) rather than "sockets.io"?  Also, it seems like your answer could be improved by addressing the OP's question about `message.type` with some syntax-specific explanations-- your answer might be a little too general and abstract.  Further, it would seem prudent that you disclose your affiliation with your web service, plugged on your blog...

Answer (score 2):

WebRTC creates peer to peer (P2P) connection between two endpoints (eg.: browsers). To do that it needs a signaling process to connect the peers, after that they are communicating directly between each other (media or data).

Signaling is need because direct communication between client applications on the Internet is very tricky due to network address translators (NATs), firewalls, and other network barriers.

**To answer your question (signaling):**

Signaling is used to exchange session control messages (*offer*, *answer*) known as SDP (Session Description Protocol format), network configurations as *ICE candidates* and media capabilities using same session control messages.

[More details about the signaling process](https://temasys.io/webrtc-ice-sorcery/)

[Anatomy of a WebRTC SDP](https://webrtchacks.com/sdp-anatomy/)

Example SDP:

```
v=0
o=- 7614219274584779017 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=-
t=0 0
a=group:BUNDLE audio video
a=msid-semantic: WMS
m=audio 1 RTP/SAVPF 111 103 104 0 8 107 106 105 13 126
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=rtcp:1 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=ice-ufrag:W2TGCZw2NZHuwlnf
a=ice-pwd:xdQEccP40E+P0L5qTyzDgfmW
a=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level
a=mid:audio
a=rtcp-mux
a=crypto:1 AES_CM_128_HMAC_SHA1_80 inline:9c1AHz27dZ9xPI91YNfSlI67/EMkjHHIHORiClQe
a=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2
…
```

[SDP testing tool](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/create-offer/).

This image shows you the whole WebRTC signaling process:

[image: Complete WebRTC signaling]